# opencv dll error - can't locate procedure LoadPackagedLibrary in KERNEL32.dll

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv, dll, tbb

I have an simple OpenCV program that runs ALL OK using pre-built dll. But when I switch to
my own dll, the app crashes with error:

*The procedure entry point **LoadPackagedLibrary** could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll*

My system:
CPU:   Intel Core i5-3210M 2.5 GHz
GPU: NV GeForce 650m
OS: Windows7 64 bit
CUDA Toolkit: 5.0
OpenCV ver: 2.4.5
OpenCV Build Option(CMake): VS2010 WIN64 TBB IPP OPENGL CUDA 
C++ Compiler for my app: VS2012
C++ Compiler for OpenCV: VS2010
DLL used for app: opencv_core245.dll tbb.dll 
app Build Option: release x64

What's wrong with my opencv_core245.dll?

Comment: I am having the same problem on Windows 7 with OpenCV 3.0.0 with TBB

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN documentation - [LoadPackagedLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Minimum supported client is Windows 8, not Windows 7, so is impossible use this function.